# Vue does not correctly remove item from vfor

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-model

I have this custom component in vue callled "dm-vehicle-spec"

```
 <dm-vehicle-spec @_handleRemoveSpec="_handleRemoveSpec" v-for="spec, index in vehicleSpecs" :key="index" :index="index" :spec="spec"></dm-vehicle-spec>
```

which looks like the following

```
<script>

export default {
    props: ["spec"],

    data() {
        return {
            specName: null,
            specValue: null,
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        if (this.spec.detail_name && this.spec.detail_value) {
            this.specName = this.spec.detail_name;
            this.specValue = this.spec.detail_value;
        }
    },  

    computed: {
        getSpecNameInputName() {
            return `spec_${this.spec.id}_name`;
        },

        getSpecValueInputName() {
            return `spec_${this.spec.id}_value`;
        },
    },

    methods: {
        _handleRemoveSpec() {
            this.$emit("_handleRemoveSpec", this.spec.id);
        }
    },
}

</script>

<template>
    <div class="specs-row flex gap-2 w-full items-center">
        <div class="col-1 w-5/12">
            <input placeholder="Naam" type="text" :id="getSpecNameInputName" class="w-full h-12 spec_name rounded-lg border-2 border-primary pl-2" v-model="specName">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2 w-5/12">
            <input placeholder="Waarde" type="text" :id="getSpecValueInputName" class="w-full h-12 spec_name rounded-lg border-2 border-primary pl-2" v-model="specValue">
        </div>
        <div @click="_handleRemoveSpec" class="col-3 w-2/12 flex items-center justify-center">
            <i class="fas fa-trash text-lg"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

so when i have 3 specs, 1 from the database and 2 customs i have the following array **vehicleSpecs** (Which i loop over)

```
[
   {"id":23,"vehicle_id":"1","detail_name":"Type","detail_value":"Snel","created_at":"2022-11-07T19:06:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-11-07T19:06:26.000000Z","deleted_at":null}, 
   {"id":24},
   {"id":25}
]
```

[image]

so lets say i want to remove the second item from the list so the one with test1 as values,  then the array looks like

```
[{"id":23,"vehicle_id":"1","detail_name":"Type","detail_value":"Snel","created_at":"2022-11-07T19:06:26.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-11-07T19:06:26.000000Z","deleted_at":null},{"id":25}]
```

So the second array item is removed and thats correct because object with id 24 no longer exsist but my html shows

[image]

that the value for object with id 24 still exists but the value for object with id 25 is removed, how is that possible?

If u need any more code or explaination, let me know

Any help or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index is not a good choice to use as v-for key.
Indexes are changing when you delete something from array.
Try using another property as a key.

Answer (score 0):

Run the loop in reverse order. This way, deleted items do not effect the remaining item indexes

Hit: indexReverse = list.length - index